# Clean install HD problems

Tags: 11.04, installation, sata

Just got a brand new box (MSI H61M motherboard) and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 on it from a CD I just burned.

Right off the bat, if I try to install from CD it loads directly into BusyBox with:

```
Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Sounds like a SATA mode problem, which by default is in IDE mode. So, if I try changing to AHCI mode, I manage to boot with the CD, but the install will not continue. When I check `df` I see that indeed the hard disk is not identified.

What is the proper procedure for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it turns out there was another BIOS option I missed.

SATA mode should be set also on `External SATA drives`.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a ThinkPad T420 and tried to install Ubuntu, and got this error. So I went to the BIOS setup and at the "Config" tab, "Serial ATA (SATA)" option, I changed the "SATA Controller Mode Option" from "Compatibility" to "AHCI". Then I got Ubuntu booted up.

(I know this is NOT the issue of the OP, but this is the only question talking about this error when installing from CD, except for one using MacBook which is pretty outside my domain :) )