# Why is my SSD periodically hanging for 20 to 30 seconds?

Tags: ssd, syslog

I was using Shotcut today when this happened, but it also happens doing other things too, maybe 2 to 5 times per day. It happened in 18.04, 18.10, and now 19.04. The laptop hangs with the SSD light illuminated for 20 to 30 seconds. I had previously increased my swapfile, thinking that might resolve it, but it didn't. I finally took a look at syslog during the hang up, but I don't understand what's happening or how to fix it. My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad T420. My SSD is a Crucial 240 GB BX300.

```
Jun 27 15:09:06 ThinkPad org.gnome.Nautilus[12476]: [Debug  ] <TimelineDock::setSelection> Changing selection to (4)  trackIndex -1 isMultitrack false
Jun 27 15:09:06 ThinkPad org.gnome.Nautilus[12476]: [Warning] <> file:///snap/shotcut/47/Shotcut.app/share/shotcut/qml/filters/contrast/ui.qml:178: TypeError: Cannot read property 'animateIn' of null
Jun 27 15:09:06 ThinkPad org.gnome.Nautilus[12476]: [Warning] <> file:///snap/shotcut/47/Shotcut.app/share/shotcut/qml/modules/Shotcut/Controls/Preset.qml:40: TypeError: Cannot read property 'presets' of null
Jun 27 15:09:22 ThinkPad org.gnome.Nautilus[12476]: [Warning] <MLT> [consumer sdl2_audio] audio timed out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188651] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xffffffff SErr 0x50000 action 0x6 frozen
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188662] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188669] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188680] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:00:10:08:10/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 8192 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188680]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188685] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188689] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188699] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:08:28:08:10/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188699]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188703] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188706] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188715] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:10:70:08:10/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188715]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188718] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188722] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188730] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:18:80:08:90/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188730]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188734] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188737] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188745] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:20:90:09:90/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188745]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188749] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188752] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188761] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:28:18:20:91/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188761]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188764] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188768] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188776] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:30:20:1f:d4/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188776]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188780] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188783] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188792] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:38:18:9c:d4/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188792]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188795] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188799] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188807] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:40:18:08:10/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188807]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188811] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188814] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188823] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:48:38:08:d0/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188823]          res 40/00:01:30:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188826] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188830] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188838] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:50:48:08:d0/00:00:08:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188838]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188842] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188846] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188854] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:58:80:08:50/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188854]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188858] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188861] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188870] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:60:58:14:50/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 8192 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188870]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188873] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188877] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188885] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:68:18:a6:51/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188885]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188889] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188892] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188901] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:70:78:15:54/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188901]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188904] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188907] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188916] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:78:c0:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188916]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188919] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188923] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188931] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:80:c8:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188931]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188935] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188938] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188947] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:88:d0:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188947]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188950] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188954] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188962] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:90:d8:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188962]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188966] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188969] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188978] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:98:e0:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 8192 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188978]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188981] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188985] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188993] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:a0:30:6c:d4/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188993]          res 40/00:fe:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.188997] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189000] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189008] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:a8:a0:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189008]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189012] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189015] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189024] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:b0:a8:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189024]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189027] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189031] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189039] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:b8:b0:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189039]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189042] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189046] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189054] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:c0:f0:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189054]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189058] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189061] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189070] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:c8:f8:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq dma 8192 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189070]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189073] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189077] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189085] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:d0:08:09:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq dma 8192 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189085]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189089] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189092] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189100] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:d8:18:09:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189100]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189104] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189107] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189116] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:e0:20:09:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189116]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189119] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189123] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189131] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:e8:28:09:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189131]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189135] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189138] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189147] ata1.00: cmd 61/80:f0:00:5f:94/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 65536 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189147]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189150] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189154] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189162] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:f8:b8:08:2d/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 4096 out
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189162]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189166] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 27 15:09:45 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.189174] ata1: hard resetting link
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.503704] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.506053] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.506060] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.506064] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.510337] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.510345] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.510349] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511361] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511651] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511654] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511656] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511659] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511662] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511665] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511669] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511672] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511678] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511680] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511683] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511686] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511688] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511692] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511695] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511697] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511700] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511702] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511705] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511707] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511710] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad kernel: [22560.511762] ata1: EH complete
Jun 27 15:09:46 ThinkPad org.gnome.Nautilus[12476]: [Info   ] <MLT> [consumer sdl2_audio] Audio Opened: driver=pulseaudio channels=2 frequency=48000
Jun 27 15:10:04 ThinkPad org.gnome.Nautilus[12476]: [Debug  ] <Timeline::MoveClipCommand::undo> fromTrack 6 toTrack 6
```

EDIT (added) Here is smartctl

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-19-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     CT240BX300SSD1
Serial Number:    1741E104FCEF
Firmware Version: M2CR010
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jun 27 16:31:44 2019 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3806
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       525
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       52
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       134
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4099138784
247 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39803537
248 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20033857

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
    6        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

EDIT (added) Here is smartctl selftest

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-19-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       223         -
```

EDIT (added) Since grub with noncq

```
Jun 28 12:54:29 ThinkPad systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Jun 28 12:54:29 ThinkPad systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jun 28 12:54:38 ThinkPad gjs[4995]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 28 12:54:40 ThinkPad zeitgeist-fts[6656]: Unable to get info on application://nemo-desktop.desktop
Jun 28 12:54:40 ThinkPad systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_UfNsWh.mount: Succeeded.
Jun 28 12:54:40 ThinkPad systemd[4253]: tmp-snap.rootfs_UfNsWh.mount: Succeeded.
Jun 28 12:54:44 ThinkPad gnome-shell[4450]: g_environ_setenv: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Jun 28 12:55:09 ThinkPad zeitgeist-datah[6641]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:210: Error during inserting events: Timeout was reached
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.815975] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x50000 action 0x6 frozen
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.815995] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake }
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.816001] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE DMA
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.816010] ata1.00: cmd ca/00:08:58:74:99/00:00:00:00:00/e8 tag 7 dma 4096 out
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.816010]          res 40/00:fe:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.816014] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  953.816021] ata1: hard resetting link
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.135513] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.138257] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.138265] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.138269] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.144892] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.144901] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.144905] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.145982] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 28 12:55:12 ThinkPad kernel: [  954.147551] ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: May you post the output of ```smartctl -a /dev/(drivename)``` ? You may have to install the "smartmontools" package before you can run it. Looks like these errors may be due to a bad drive

Comment: @Gordster I was afraid of that. I added that output above in my question.

Comment: Is this a desktop? Did you change any hardware?  I have seen these errors happen when using a sata 1 or sata 2 cable with a sata 3 connector. It can also be that the PSU is too weak.It could also be an issue with the connector or the cable.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is a ThinkPad T420 laptop. I took the original HDD and moved that to a caddy in the old CD location. Then I put a SSD in the hard drive location. I'm using the SSD for the system and the HDD for data storage. All this was done before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm. I assume you used one of those small connectors to convert from hdd to ssd? Not sure if those can create those messages :-P sorry

Comment: Only other thing I would say is to run ```smartctl -t long /dev/(drivename)``` then wait for the test to complete (about 10 minutes) and then repost the output of ```smartctl -l selftest /dev/(drivename)```

Comment: @Gordster I ran the selftest and added that output above in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important to check for a SSD firmware update. Your current firmware is M2CR010. Go to https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/support-ssd-firmware to check for newer firmware.

If your firmware is current, then you may have a NCQ problem.

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued FPDMA error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**Update #1:**

Also changed the BIOS setting for the SATA controller from **AHCI** to **Compatibility**.

Comment: No firmware updates are available for BX300. I will try the extra parameter. Thanks again!

Comment: I just experienced a hang since adding the extra parameter. I will post the hung syslog lines in my question above.

Comment: @ticotexas the NCQ patch may have helped, even though there may still be more wrong. See my comment in your newer question.

Comment: @ticotexas see https://askubuntu.com/questions/62904/clean-install-hd-problems/122066#122066

Comment: I've done the opposite of the link you provided. I went into BIOS and changed SATA from 'AHCI' to 'compatibility'. (It was already set to AHCI.) I'll see what happens.

Comment: No hangs so far with noncq and BIOS SATA set to 'compatibility'.

Comment: For me, changing bios from AHCI to compatibility was sufficient without any other boot parameters.